# Modulo returns wrong result when using negatives

Tags: c, modulo

I want to calculate:
(-15 % 3) which should be 0 but instead i'm getting 1:

When i explicitly do:

```
int IntFcn (const void *key, size_t tableSize)
{
    printf("%d\n",(*(int*)key)); // prints -15
    printf("%d\n",tableSize); // prints 3
    printf("%d\n",(-15) % 3); // prints 0
}
```

I get the right result (0) but when i try to use the variables below i get 1:

```
int IntFcn (const void *key, size_t tableSize)
{
    printf("%d\n",(*(int*)key)); // prints -15
    printf("%d\n",tableSize); // prints 3
    printf("%d\n",((*(int*)key) % tableSize)); // prints 1
    return ((*(int*)key) % tableSize);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show us how you called all these functions please?

Comment: Don't printf() a size_t argument as "%d". Either cast to (unsigned int) and use a "%u" spec, or use the "%zu" specifier. Note: printf() is a varargs function, so you should be very carefull with the types of the arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second case the second operand of modulo is unsigned integer thus the first operand is promoted to unsigned as well before performing the modulo. So the result will be `(unsigned)(-15) % 3` which is equal (for 32-bit `int`) to `4294967281 % 3 == 1`.

Comment: how can i overcome this if i want this to work on both 32/64 bit machines?

Comment: It's not related to 32/64 bits. It's a matter of signed/unsigned arithmetic operations. Your operand is being promoted to unsigned when you don't expect it to. Cast explicitly to `int` to prevent the effect: `((*(int*)key) % (int)tableSize)`

Comment: I would suggest that, assuming tablesize may get LARGE on a 64-bit machine [hence the use of size_t?], that using casts to `long` would be a better choice than `int`. But otherwise agree.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I agree in general. But in this case it's probably ok since key to that table is `int`

Answer (score 1):

try this..

`return ((*(int*)key) % (int)tableSize);`